# conftest.py ImportError: No module named Foo

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following directory structure

```
/home/ubuntu/test/
 - Foo/
   - Foo.py
   - __init__.py
 - Test/
   - conftest.py
   - __init__.py
   - Foo/
     - test_Foo.py
     - __init__.py
```

Foo.py contains

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

conftest.py contains:

```
import pytest

import sys
print sys.path

from Foo.Foo import Foo

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def foo():
  return Foo()
```

test_Foo.py contains:

```
class TestFoo():
  def test___init__(self,foo):
    assert True
```

If I run pytest . in the Test folder then I get an error that it can not find the module Foo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/pythonVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 379, in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
  File "/home/ubuntu/pythonVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_path/local.py", line 662, in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
  File "/home/ubuntu/pythonVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 212, in load_module
    py.builtin.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
  File "/home/ubuntu/pythonVirtualEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_builtin.py", line 221, in exec_
    exec2(obj, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 7, in exec2
  File "/home/ubuntu/test/Test/conftest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Foo.Foo import Foo
ImportError: No module named Foo
ERROR: could not load /home/ubuntu/test/Test/conftest.py
```

The sys.path that is printed out in conftest.py seems to include the /home/ubuntu/test path so it should be able to find Foo.py, right?

The thing is that it only works when I move conftest.py to the folder below.

I run  pytest 3.2.2

Comment: In `conftest.py`, try `from .Foo.Foo import Foo`. The extra `.` backs you out of the `Test` directory before attempting to import the `Foo` module.

Comment: Does that work for you? I tried, but it doesn't seem to work for me. The thing is that it works when I move conftest.py to the folder below.

Answer (score 7):

The error says the `conftest.py` can not be loaded because of an `ImportError`. Try moving your import inside the foo fixture like this:

```
import pytest
import sys
print sys.path


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def foo():
    from Foo.Foo import Foo
    return Foo()
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would recommend you do is set up a virtual environment and install the Foo module in the virtual environment.

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
. ./venv/bin/activate
```

In order to install your local modules you need a `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.0.1',
    author='My Name',
    author_email='my.name@email.com',
    packages=['Foo'],
)
```

Then you can install your Foo module within your virtual environment: `pip install -e .`. Then when you run your tests, they will pick up your module.

For a more complete, long term way of doing this, consider using requirements files.
I usually put the modules I need in two files named `requirements.txt` (for production) and `requirements-test.txt`(for running tests).
So in `requirements.txt` put what you need for your Foo class, e.g.

```
json
flask==1.0.2
```

where have specified the version for `flask` but not `json`. Then in the `requirements-test.txt` file you put the following:

```
-r requirements.txt
pytest
-e .
```

The first line means that when you install `requirements-test.txt` you get all the `requirements.txt` as well. The `-e .` is the magic that fixes the problem you've experienced here, i.e. it installs the Foo module (and any others you might have in this repo).

To install the `requirements-test.txt` file you then run:

```
pip install -r requirements-test.txt
```

Now you can run your tests and it will find your Foo module. This is a good way to solve the problem in CI as well.